# php text to image imagettftext()

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$image= imagecreate(120,50);

$txt="hello world!";
$bg=    imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
$clr=   imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);

imagettftext($image,12,0,5,35,$clr,'font.ttf',$txt);


imagejpeg($image);
```

---

this works on local xampp server on windows 7
but when i upload it to server it does not show image

---

but when i replace imagettftext() with imagestring() then it works,
and i am sure i have uploaded font.ttf file.

Comment: Is font.ttf available on your server?

Comment: i have solved it  
by replacing   
imagettftext($image,12,0,5,35,$clr,**'font.ttf'**,$txt); with     
imagettftext($image,12,0,5,35,$clr,**'./font.ttf'**,$txt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'SomeFont';
?>
```

From php manual